# Regex to validate phone Number for repeating digits

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regular expression to validate phone numbers. Those that have `111.111.1111` format should succeed. Others, like `789-123-1234`, should fail.

I have come up with `^(\d)(\1+$)\d*$` regex, but it only helps validate `1111111111` and not `111.111.1111`. Can anyone help me improve my regex?

Comment: Just one explanation - numbers MUST be repeated? 111.222.3333 isn't valid format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{4}$` to validate numbers containing digits from 0 to 9. If you plan to only match just one-digit numbers (like '111.111.1111', '222.222.2222'), use `^([0-9])\1{2}\.\1{3}\.\1{4}$`

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there: capture the first digit and check for repititions, like this `^(\d){2}\.\1{3}\.\1{4}$`.

Comment: i missed out ^(\d)\1[2}\.\1{3}\.\1{4}$  this does validate 111.111.1111 but not 1111111111

Comment: puzzled...if you want to validate number with or without dots, you can make the literal dot in the pattern optional by placing a '?' just behind it:`^(\d){2}\.?\1{3}\.?\1{4}$` (btw there was a typo in my regex string, corrected now.)

Answer (score 0):

matching (111) 111-1111

```
^\(([0-9])\1{2}\)\s\1{3}\-\1{4}$
```

matching 111.111.1111

```
^([0-9])\1{2}\.\1{3}\.\1{4}$
```

matching 111-111-1111

```
^([0-9])\1{2}\-\1{3}\-\1{4}$
```